# Java Client SDK for Hyperledger blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, java-client

Under https://github.com/hyperledger there are many Java Client SDK projects like fabric-gateway / fabric-gateway-java / fabric-sdk-java.

Why are there so many Java clients?

How do I choose which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate it could be more obvious. The README for each repo does give some guidance. From the [**fabric-sdk-java**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) README:

> This project provides a low-level API for interacting with Hyperledger Fabric blockchain networks, and is used by the high-level Hyperledger Fabric Gateway SDK for Java [...] For building Hyperledger Fabric blockchain client applications, you are strongly encouraged to use the high level API.

That points to [**fabric-gateway-java**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway-java) as the API to use.

From Fabric v2.4, the [**fabric-gateway**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway) client API is the preferred client API for developing applications. It provides a consistent client API in Go, Node and Java, with much of the heavy-lifting moved to a server-side Fabric Gateway service, implemented in the peer.